# Multiple horizontal alignment points in equation

Tags: equations, amsmath

This seems like it would be easy, but I don't see an environment that accounts for this. I'd like to horizontally align corresponding elements in a multi-line equation.

```
Σk^2 = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n
         + 2 + 3 + ... + n
             + 3 + ... + n
                   ... 
                       + n
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What should be aligned, exactly?

Comment: Hi, I'd like it to result graphically like the code snippet above. I've used the align* environment frequently, but that would only allow the first alignment point. I want all of the 2's, 3's, ...'s, n's aligned correspondingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your typesetting objective is much easier to achieve with an `array` environment than it is with an `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumtype" macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operators
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r} & automatic display-style math mode

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\begin{array}{R*{5}{CR}}
\sum k^2 & = & 1 & + & 2 & + & 3 & + & \cdots & + & n \\
         &   &   & + & 2 & + & 3 & + & \cdots & + & n \\
         &   &   &   &   & + & 3 & + & \cdots & + & n \\
         &   &   &   &   &   &   & + & \cdots & + & n \\
         &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \cdots &   &   \\
         &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &        & + & n 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `alignat`. I replaced the last `\cdots` with a `vdots` aligned with the last `+` signs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
\sum k^2 = 1 +{} & 2 &{}+{}& 3 & + & \cdots & + & n \\
       {}+{}& 2 &{}+{} & 3 &{}+{}& \cdots &{}+{} & n \\
          & & {}+{}& 3 & {}+{} & \cdots & {}+{} & n \\
            & & & & {}+{}& \cdots & {}+{} & n \\[-1.5ex]
        & & & & & & \vdotswithin{ + }& \\[-1ex]
         & & & & & & {}+{}& n
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is also an easy, and elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can exploit the symmetry and the fact that the first column in `aligned` is right aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\sum k^2 = 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n \\
          {} + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n \\
              {} + 3 + \cdots + n \\
                  {} + \cdots + n \\
\vdotswithin{+}\hphantom{n} \\
                           {} + n
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]